# How can I use data.table to calculate a cumulative-so-far sum across subsets?

Tags: r, data.table

In this MVCE snippet, why is it not possible to use `.SD[1:round]` in this way?

And is there a way to twist `data.table` into submission?

```
> test <- data.table(event = c(1,1,1,2,2), round = c(seq(1,3),seq(1,2)), cost = seq(20,60,10))
> test
   event round cost
1:     1     1   20
2:     1     2   30
3:     1     3   40
4:     2     4   50
5:     2     5   60

> test[,.(cumulative=sum(.SD[1:round]$cost)),by=.(event)]
   event cumulative
1:     1         20
2:     2         NA
Warning messages:
1: In 1:round : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
2: In 1:round : numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
```

**Desired Result**:

```
   event round cumulative
1:     1     1         20
2:     1     2         50
3:     1     3         90
4:     2     1         50
5:     2     2        110
```

Comment: What are you trying to get as a result?

Comment: You mean `test[, cmsum:= cumsum(cost), by=event]`?

Comment: @Sotos updated the question

Comment: @Sotos yes! Where is this `cumsum` behaviour documented (in the context of `data.table`)?

Comment: Just type `?cumsum` in your console

Comment: I get how it works now. If you put it down as an answer I'll gladly accept

Comment: Well its duplicated actually so I ll just hammer